# `find_by_*_id` does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the book [Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) and I'm having a trouble with a failing test case.

I wrote a test that checks that when you add a duplicate item into a cart, the number of items does not change, but the quantity changes

```
  test 'adding duplicate products to cart' do
    cart = Cart.new

    ruby_book = products(:ruby)
    cart.add_product ruby_book.id

    assert cart.line_items.length == 1
    assert cart.total_price == ruby_book.price

    p '-------start--------'
    p 'outside add_product'
    p "line_items: #{cart.line_items}"
    cart.add_product ruby_book.id

    assert cart.line_items.length == 1  # TEST FAILS HERE with length == 2
    assert cart.total_price == ruby_book.price * 2 
  end
```

It basically tests the `add_product` method, which is:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    p 'inside add_product'
    p "line_items: #{line_items}"
    p "product_id: #{product_id}"
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    p "current_item: #{current_item}"
    p '---------end---------'
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
      current_item.price += current_item.product.price
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
      current_item.price = current_item.product.price
    end 
    current_item
  end 

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.price }
  end 
end
```

To debug the test I added some print calls (as you see). The output is:

```
"-------start--------"
"outside add_product"
"line_items: [#<LineItem id: nil, product_id: 207281424, cart_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7fa491744fe0,'0.4999E2',18(45)>>]"
"inside add_product"
"line_items: [#<LineItem id: nil, product_id: 207281424, cart_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7fa491744fe0,'0.4999E2',18(45)>>]"
"product_id: 207281424"
"current_item: "
"---------end---------"
```

I can see that `line_items` has an item with `product_id: 207281424` but for some reason the call `line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)` does not return the item, but returns `nil`. Why?

Comment: The core issue is that find_by_id will always hot the database, so won't find unsaved records. In addition you'll be modifying a separate (in memory) object from the one in the line_items association, so unless you reload that the data will become stale

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `add_cart` method. There in the else block you are just building a `line_item` object, but you are not saving it anywhere. Change you else block to,

```
else
  current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
  current_item.price = current_item.product.price
  current_item.save
end
```

Comment: this does not help; also the `add_product` method is from the book, so  the problem should be in how I test it. Note that the application itself works as expected, the problem should be in the test.

Answer (score 0):

`add_product` method does not save the line item in the db, try to call `save` on returned item

```
...
ruby_book = products(:ruby)
item = cart.add_product ruby_book.id
item.save

assert cart.line_items.length == 1
assert cart.total_price == ruby_book.price


item = cart.add_product ruby_book.id
item.save

assert cart.line_items.length == 1
...
```

Comment: if I do that it fails on line `assert cart.total_price == ruby_book.price * 2` with price being half of expected

Comment: As @kwon said, `total_sum` for the cart in your code is calculated incorrectly. Guess it should be something like `line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }`

Answer (score 0):

#### dimuch is correct. You are not saving your items to your cart.

`current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)` would return `nil` and cause you to build another `line_item` if you do not save. Causing your test to return 2 instead of 1.

#### And then there is the problem of your `total_price` method.

```
line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.price }
```

In your scenario (with save to db) would only sum **1** line item, since you are adding the same product twice. Without saving (to db) the math would be correct as each line item would act as 1 quantity.

Since quantity is defined per line item, you need make sure you are applying quantity to your calculation.

```
line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.price * item.quantity }
```